# ggplot2() bar chart and dplyr() grouped and overall data in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to make a stacked proportional bar chart representing the prevalence of diabetes in a cohort of individuals residing in towns A, B, and C. I'd also like the plot to feature a bar representing the entire cohort.

I'm happy with the below plot, but I'd like to know if there is a way of incorporating the pre-processing step into the processing step, ie piping it with dplyr()?

Thanks!

Starting point (df):

```
dfa <- data.frame(town=c("A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C","C"),diabetes=c("y","y","n","n","y","n","y","n","n","y"),heartdisease=c("n","y","y","n","y","y","n","n","n","y"))
```

Pre-processing:

```
dfb <- rbind(dfa, transform(dfa, town = "ALL"))
```

Processing and plot:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

dfc <- dfb %>%
group_by(town) %>%
count(diabetes) %>%
mutate(prop = n / sum(n))

ggplot(dfc, aes(x = town, y = prop, fill = diabetes)) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
dfc <- dfa %>%
  bind_rows(dfa %>%
              mutate(town = "ALL")) %>%
  group_by(town) %>%
  count(diabetes) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = town, y = prop, fill = diabetes)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    coord_flip()
```

**EDIT:** added pre-processing into pipeline using `bind_rows` and `mutate` instead of `rbind` and `transform`

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear, I meant how to incorporate what's happening in dfb <- rbind(dfa, transform(dfa, town = "ALL")) into dfc <- dfb %>% group_by(town) %>%count(diabetes) %>%mutate(prop = n / sum(n)).

Comment: I changed the answer to include the preprocessing steps in the pipeline